# React - assign component to array variables

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to assign component to variable in React?
I want something like this:

```js
records[0] = {
  return(
    <Row key={'myValue'}>
      {myValue}
    </Row>
  )
}

records[0] = {
  return(
    <Row key={'mySecondValue'}>
      {mySecondValue}
    </Row>
  )
}
```

So then I can sort this array (records) based on other array and display.

Comment: Sure, but having a `return` there is nonsensical. So are the curly-braces. And two `records[0]`. But that's not how you'd do it IRL, you'd have an array of data, each element rendered by a component, and when it's sorted, it would be re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks for answer Dave! Yeah, there should be records[1] in second element of array. I also wrote it with "return", because thats how am I doing this while using map function. Sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just do :

```
const records = [
  <Row key={'myValue'}>{myValue}</Row>,
  <Row key={'mySecondValue'}>{mySecondValue}</Row>
]
```

Comment: for bigger structures you can wrap components into parenthesis

Comment: Thank you dashton and zmii!

Answer (score 0):

there is two ways:

```
const Element = ({title}) => <h1>{title}</h1>;

//as a callback
elements[0] = ({title}) => <Element title={title}/>;

//and then invoke it like:
const anotherElement = () => <>{elements[0]('MyTitle')</>

//or
elements[0] = ({title}) => Element;
const anotherElement = () => <elements[0] title={'MyTitle'}/>
```